# mixed up network configuration in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, sharing, netplan

Recently upgraded to 18.04 from 14.04 (in steps of course)

Just about everything works. Have network access, and remote access via ssh.

Desktop sharing (VNC) however doesn't work and can't be enabled. When I'm trying to enable, it shows "no networks selected for sharing" as shown below

Screen Sharing config:

[image: screen sharing dialog showing no networks selected]

Dug in a bit and found that I can't access NetworkManager GUI. `/etc/network/interfaces` still exists and configures eth0. nmtui works however...

`netplan generate` doesn't generate anything. Created a yaml file under `/etc/netplan` pointing to NetworkManager as renderer, but `netplan apply` doesn't fix my problem...

By the way, nmtui shows the netplan-eth0 interface but it is not active, nor can it be activated...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading an existing installation does not replace `/etc/network/interfaces` with netplan, and if `/etc/network/interfaces` exists and is populated, NetworkManager respects this configuration and treats those devices as unmanaged.

If you want to manage eth0 with NetworkManager, you need to delete / comment out the configuration for this interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`.